# Entropy and Maximum Mutual Information

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Question: Given RV's $X$ and $Y$ with ranges $\{0, 1, 2\}$ and $\{0, 1\}$, how large can $I(X;Y)$ be?

**Attempt at Solution:**

I know that $I(X;Y)$ is less than or equal to $H(X)$, so I am assuming that if I calculate $H(X)$, then I'll know the maximum value that $I(X;Y)$ can be.  If I'm just given the range of $X$, then should I just assume that each $X$ value has a probability of $\frac{1}{3}$, since there are $3$ $X$ values?  I'm not even sure if I'm thinking about this correctly...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Note that $I(X;Y) \le \min(H(X), H(Y)),$ not just $H(X)$ (to show this, exchange $X$ and $Y$ and appeal to the symmetry of $I$.) Here, the support of $Y$ is smaller than the support of $X$, and thus $\sup H(Y) = \log 2$ is a better upper bound, and is achieved by the uniform distribution on $Y$.

Comment: (contd.) The natural question is if this value can ever be achieved by $I(X;Y)$. i.e., does there exists a $P_{X|Y} $ s.t. for $P_Y$ the uniform distribution, $I(X;Y) = H(Y) = \log 2.$ Note that for this to hold, we must have that $H(Y|X) = 0$ (why?). Can you construct such a joint distribution? (Hint - think of a typewriter with 3 keys, two of which are stuck together.)